# How to set timeout value for a @WebMethod in a @Stateless bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timeout, stateless

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to set the timeout value for a web method in a @Stateless bean. Or even if it is possible. I have searched quite a bit and found nothing related to this question.

Example:

```
@WebService
@Stateless
public class Test {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "hello")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any answers.

Comment: You set the timeout in the web service consumer, not in the producer.

Comment: Hi Luiggi, Thanks a lot. I will not search anymore in that direction... It would have been great to be able to "force" the consumers to wait for a minimum time ;)

Comment: @Emmanuel Well, what you are trying to do is not unheard of, better, it is provided by the new EJB 3.1 specification, using the `@AccessTimeout` annotation.

Comment: @Carlo, Thanks I will try it, but I am not sure it is what I am looking for. It seems to be about concurrent access and not how many time a web method has to answer to a client before a timeout occurs. The AccessTimeOut annotation documentation says: "Specifies the amount of time in a given time unit that a concurrent access attempt should block before timing out. A value of 0 means concurrent access is not permitted. A value of -1 means wait indefinitely to acquire a lock. Values less than -1 are not valid. " A try worths anyway the shot. Thanks

Comment: @Emmanuel Yes `@AccessTimeout` throws an exception only if the *access*  timeout is exceeded (i.e when thread exhaustion or other concurrency constraints block the access to the method). There is no (portable) way to timeout the method execution per se.

Comment: @Carlo Your Comment was useful, thanks, I have respond to the question, telling how I have solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after searching and learning a little bit I have solved this problem by doing the following: I have created a stateless Bean that contains an @Asynchronous method:

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<String> sayHelloAsync() 
{
     //do something time consuming ...
     return new AsyncResult<String>("Hello world");
}
```

Then in a second bean exposing its method as Web Services I have done the following:

```
@WebService
@Stateless
public class Test {

     @EJB
     FirstBean myFirstBean;//first bean containing the Async method.

    /**
     * Can be used in futher methods to follow
     * the running web service method
     */
    private Future<String> myAsyncResult;

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "hello")
    public String sayHello(@WebParam(name = "timeout_in_seconds") long timeout)
    {
        myAsyncResult = myFirstBean.sayHelloAsync();
        String myResult = "Service is still running";
        if(timeout>0)
        {
            try {
                myResult= myAsyncResult.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                myResult="InterruptedException occured";
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                myResult="ExecutionException occured";
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                myResult="The timeout value "+timeout+" was reached."+ 
                                 " The Service is still running.";
            }
        }
        return myResult;
    }
}
```

If the timeout is set, then the client will wait this amount of time until it is reached. The process still has to run in my case. I hope it will help others.